# Question about powering a small vibration motor

Tags: mosfet, esp8266

I have a SparkFun ESP8266 Thing board that is powered by 1 Ah battery. My goal is to toggle a small 10 mm coin motor on and off. The GPIO pins provide very small current (12 mA) which results in a vibration that's quite weak. However, the Vin pin board can supply 500 mA which is adequate for a strong vibration in my testing.
The idea that I currently have is to use a typical MOSFET + diode + resistor circuit with the Vin pin acting as the Source and one of the GPIO pins as the Gate.One wire from the motor would be connected to the GND on the board and the other to Drain on MOSFET. Would this work? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Assuming an N-Channel MOSFET, then: Source to Ground, Drain to Motor, other side of motor to Vin.You want to be switching the motor's Ground connection, not its Vin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work, assuming you get a mosfet with a gate that is fully turned on by 3.3V in, and can handle the current load of your motor (stall current not just regular load). That's pretty much how it is done, as simple as it gets.

Comment: Thanks. The most basic way of making a circuit is doing so on a breadboard but it's too large and unwieldy for my prototype which is supposed to be small, lightweight, and portable. Short of designing a custom PCB, is there another solution for creating this simple circuit with a much smaller foot print?

Comment: Well you can use copper clad board and cut a small circuit into it, or strip/vero board or even protoboard (unconnected dots). You can get strip board shaped like a breadboard. The cost of custom pcb design is super cheap too. But to be honest you can just dead bug this and wire the transistor and resistor dead bug style or "inline" https://www.summet.com/blog/2016/01/21/how-to-convert-a-denford-scantek-2000-micromill-to-linuxcnc-mach3-control-part-3-spindle-motor-control/

Comment: @user better picture https://quadmeup.com/simplest-hardware-inverter-for-flight-controller/amp/